Boy finds a new world, meets a werewolf who knew his father
Posting for a friend.
The novel (possibly YA fiction) involved a boy finding a new world, possibly underground. The boy (who's an ordinary human) finds a werewolf who knew his dad, and the boy has a silver bullet keepsake that dad had pulled out of the werewolf's chest, saving his life and so he owes the boy a debt. There were also other monsters trying to steal the boy.
Anyone recognize this?

Why are they trying to abduct him if he's a nobody?

Could this be Wereling by Steve Feasey?
The main character is a teenage boy who discovers that he is a werewolf. He is taken in by his "uncle", a man (who we subsequently learn is a vampire) that knew the main character's father.
At one point, the main character is given a silver pendant to wear that belonged to his father and was instrumental in saving the life of the vampire.
Over the course of this novel and series multiple 'netherworld' werewolves and monsters attempt to abduct the boy for various reasons.

Sadly, no. The boy wasn't a werewolf himself.
